# What does the notation $S^{n} \rightarrow S$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If S is a set and an operation on $S$ is denoted by $S^{n} \rightarrow S$, does the n in the exponent of S mean that the function's inputs are tuples of the set $S\times S \times S  \times S \space  \times \space ... \space \times S  $   (n-times)?

Comment: Yes -----------

Comment: yes, sorry for the triviality there. Just because you already know it doesn't mean that everybody getting into this topic the first time knows it...

Comment: @RubenMessi My vote to close is not personal. I'm just 1: answering your question: yes this is what it means. And 2: voting to close, because the answer to this question will help you! nothing wrong with that! but will not really benefit the site to have this question hanging around (in my opinion)

Comment: ok, as you wish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, $S^n$ denotes the set $\underbrace{S\times S\times\cdots\times S}_{n\text{ times}}$, and until some level in math education, no further explanation is usually given.

---

There is quite a profound extension of this notation.

Often, with $A^B$ we denote *the set of all functions $f:B\to A$*. The reason we call it $A^B$ and not $B^A$ is that, in the cases where $A$ and $B$ are finite, the number of those functions ($|A^B|$) is $|A|^{|B|}$, as for every element $b\in B$ we have $|A|$ possible choices in $A$ to map $b$ into.

This lets us define:

$$|A|^{|B|}:=|A^B|$$

even for infinite sets, prove that this is a well-defined operation, and this lets us use *exponentiation on cardinal numbers*.

---

On the other hand, in set theory it is often taken that:

$$n:=\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$$

(with $0:=\emptyset$), so $S^n$ may be taken as *the set of all the functions of the set (of *indices*) $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ into $S$*, i.e. as the set of all $n$-sized sequences $(s_0,s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1})$, where $s_i\in S$ for $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$.

This may not be exactly the same as $\underbrace{S\times S\times\cdots\times S}_{n\text{ times}}$ (in fact, this depends on how you define the latter), but there is an obvious bijection between those sets, so you may just as well identify $\underbrace{S\times S\times\cdots\times S}_{n\text{ times}}$ with $S^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. This is true in general. For example for $n=3$ and $S=\mathbb{Z}$, the function $f(x,y,z) = xyz$; $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$, is a function from $\mathbb{Z}^3$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ and can be written $$f: \mathbb{Z}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$